# Linear transformation that is injective in each subspace of a sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space in which $V = \sum_{i \in I} V_i$ for a collection of subspaces $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $V$ (with a sum that is not necessarily direct), and let $f : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation.

If the restriction of $f$ to each $V_i$ is injective, then $f$ may not be injective itself, because there may still be some $v_i \in V_i \setminus V_j$ and $v_j \in V_j \setminus V_i$ for some $i \neq j$ such that $f(v_i) = f(v_j)$.

So, my question is: if we assume that the restriction of $f$ to $V_i$ is injective for all $i \in I$ and that $f(V_i) \cap f(V_j) = f(V_i \cap V_j)$ for all $i$ and $j$ in $I$ (as to avoid the previous problem), then is $f$ injective?

From my drafts, this is true for $V = V_1 + V_2$, but I'm not sure if this works for an arbitrary sum of subspaces.

Comment: as arbitrary sum won't make sense in vector space, I guess you mean to prove this for finite sum, right?

Comment: I mean to prove (or disprove) for an arbitrary sum, really. In the case of a infinite sum, $\sum_{I \in I} V_i$ is the subspace of V formed by elements of the form $\sum_{i \in I} v_i$ in which $v_i \in V_i$ and only a finite amount of the v_i are not equal to zero.

Comment: Thinking about the finite case made me think I could prove this by induction for I finite. I'm gonna draft it out. Maybe a proof by induction could even be adapted to a proof for the arbitrary case, since each vector will be the sum of a finite amount of vectors.

Comment: I guess I have found a counterexample.. will update you soon

Answer (score 2):

Consider three straight lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as subspaces such that their sum is $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now map each of these line to a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane such that any two lines intersect in origin only. All conditions of your hypothesis will get satisfied but since $\mathbb{R}^3$ got mapped to $\mathbb{R}^2$, map won't be injective.

Comment: Oh, so there was such a simple counterexample. Thanks!